# How would I refactor this piece of jQuery

Tags: jquery, refactoring

How could this code be better written? I mean I'm targeting a parent of a child of a parent. I don't know how to do it but it seems like there might be a more elegant way to do it.

```
$('.flex-overlay')
    .children('.fluid-width-video-wrapper')
    .parent('.flex-overlay')
    .css({
        'border': '1px solid red',
        });
```

Comment: Please provide the HTML structure. Or create a jsfiddle.

Comment: isn't `.parent('.flex-overlay')` the first selector?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `has` method:

```
$('.flex-overlay')
     .has('.fluid-width-video-wrapper')
     .css({ 'border': '1px solid red'});
```

Comment: Or `$('.flex-overlay:has(.fluid-width-video-wrapper)')`, though performance-wise I'd query for the `.fluid-width-video-wrapper` and get their `.parent()`, I believe this would provide better performance than looking through all descendants of `.flex-overlay`. Guess performance is a little out of the scope of the question anyway. And as these are direct children it shouldn't matter much.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté, actually, I was going to post exactly that one! But, I have the feeling my answer will be badly overlooked and I rescinded from it

Comment: @Alexander I was going to post that and `:has()`, but @ undefined beat me to it and I agree that `has` facilitates reading the code. Most people that use jQuery don't really care about the microseconds like me. `:P`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté  Yes, however, `has` method is faster than `:has` selector, I think performance-wise using `filter` method is more efficient here. I will update the answer.

Comment: Interesting. I'd expect both to have nearly the same performance. I believe Sizzle would apply the `has` selector after finding all `.flex-overlay`, thus providing 1 less function call. And I'm not sure about the `filter` - you're applying a callback function to each item and creating a new jQuery object inside each iteration. Though I'm not sure whether `has` doesn't simply do that internally, probably in a more optimized way I'd hope.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yes, you are right, the `filter` is not efficient here as there are many redundant jQuery objects created. _Just an alternative_.

Comment: I think you guys will find [this jsperf](http://jsperf.com/how-would-i-refactor-this-piece-of-jquery/2) as interesting as I do. What I believed was gonna be faster, it wasn't